# Plegar y desplegar de un acordeón Bootstrap mediante un menú desplegable

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Necesito ayuda con el elemento [Accordion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/accordion/) de Bootstrap.

Lo que necesito hacer es que al seleccionar una opción del menú desplegable (`<select>`) muestre u oculte el elemento del acordeón, para poder desplegarlo al seleccionar dicha opción.

Logro mostrar u ocultar al hacer clic en el mismo acordeón, pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo al pulsar en el `<option>`.

Dejo el código que tengo ahora mismo:

**Edito:** He hecho un par de modificaciones, pero tampoco consigo hacerlo, dejo comentarios en el código para explicar lo que he hecho.

```js
const myOption1 = document.querySelector('#option1');
const collapseOption = document.querySelector('#myOptionCollapse');
const cerrarAcordeon = document.querySelector('#colapsarAcordeon');

// Aqui he seleccionado el option y he intentado hacer que elimine el show en el div y agregue la clase "collapsed" al boton

myOption1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  collapseOption.classList.remove('show');
  collapseOption.classList.add('collapsed');
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="./assets/js/main.js" type="module"></script>
  <title>Document</title tle>
</head>
<body>
  <select class="form-select rarius misas-collapse search__select" id="floatingSelect" aria-label="Floating label select">
    <option selected>Seleccionar zona</option>

    <!-- He agregado ID a los option y quitado las clases para recogerlos con el DOM -->
    <option id="option1">option 1</option>
    <option id="option2">option 2</option>
  </select>
  <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">

      <!-- en este boton aparece la clase "collapsed" al tiempo que se elimina la clase "show", esto lo hace bootstrap para abrir o cerrar el acordeon -->
      <button class="accordion-button option1" id="colapsarAcordeon" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>

    <!-- aqui he agregado el ID myOptionCollapse para recogerlo tambien con el DOM -->
    <div id="collapseOne myOptionCollapse" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar en tu ejemplo qué intentaste hacer en el `option`? Tal cual como está, el evento está en el _accordion-header_, no en el `select`. No olvides mostrar en el [repro] _lo que intentaste hasta el momento, relacionado a tu problema_.

Comment: A ver si lo entiendo... ¿quieres que al pulsar en el desplegable TUYO (y no del acordeón) se cambie el estado de la opción del acordeón que has marcado, ¿verdad?

Comment: Sí, cuando seleccione una opción, despliegue el acordeón, que se hace agregando la clase "show"

Comment: Respuesta redactada con enlace a la documentación y un ejemplo de cómo juntarlo todo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te dejo enlace a la documentación:

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/collapse/#methods

He hecho la siguiente modificación a tu HTML para que funcione:

```
<select ... onchange="cambio(this)">
    <option selected>Seleccionar zona</option>
    <option value="collapseOne">option 1</option>
    <option value="collapseTwo">option 2</option>
</select>
```

Por un lado he cambiado el evento `onchange` para que mande como parámetro el elemento pulsado. Por otro lado he puesto un valor a cada elemento del desplegable que diga qué elemento del acordeón debe mostrar.

El código JavaScript lo divido en dos partes.

La primera crea un listado de elementos que pueden ser mostrados u ocultados con el menú:

```
/* Obtenemos todos los elementos colapsables para ocultarlos o mostrarlos */
elementos = {};
document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-collapse").forEach(elem => {
  /* Creamos una instancia de cada elemento que pueda llamar a sus métodos */
  elementos[elem.id] = new bootstrap.Collapse(elem, {
    toggle: false,
    show: false,
    hide: true,
  });
});
```

Y en segundo lugar gestionamos el evento de manera que primero ocultamos todos los elementos y, por último, mostramos únicamente el seleccionado:

```
function cambio(elemento) {
  /* Primero borramos todos los elementos */
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(elementos).forEach(indice => {
    elementos[indice].hide();
  });
  /* Mostramos solo el seleccionado (si no fue ninguno no muestra ninguno) */
  elementos[elemento.value]?.show();
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando a continuación:

```js
/* Obtenemos todos los elementos colapsables para ocultarlos o mostrarlos */
elementos = {};
document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-collapse").forEach(elem => {
  /* Creamos una instancia de cada elemento que pueda llamar a sus métodos */
  elementos[elem.id] = new bootstrap.Collapse(elem, {
    toggle: false,
    show: false,
    hide: true,
  });
});

function cambio(elemento) {
  /* Primero borramos todos los elementos */
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(elementos).forEach(indice => {
    elementos[indice].hide();
  });
  /* Mostramos solo el seleccionado (si no fue ninguno no muestra ninguno) */
  elementos[elemento.value]?.show();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="./assets/js/main.js" type="module"></script>
  <title>Document</title tle>
</head>
<body>
  <select class="form-select rarius misas-collapse search__select" id="floatingSelect" aria-label="Floating label select" onchange="cambio(this)">
    <option selected>Seleccionar zona</option>
    <option value="collapseOne">option 1</option>
    <option value="collapseTwo">option 2</option>
  </select>
  <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button option1" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias OscarGarcia!!! Es genial como lo has resuelto, funciona perfectamente!